# Can't compile android maps untils anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-maps-utils

A very uncommon problem occured to me. Everything was perfectly working and all of the sudden I couldn't compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5.+' anymore.

I couldn't find a way to fix it, so I updated Android Studio to version 3.0.1, created a new project and tried to compile just this dependency. My other dependencies cause no problems but this one is giving the error message:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5.+.
Could not find any version that matches com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5.+.
Versions that do not match:
    0.5
    0.4.4
    0.4.3
    0.4.2
    0.4.1
    + 9 more
Required by:
    project :app*
```

Does anybody has an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no version matching the 0.5.+ pattern for maputils. Use `implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'` instead.